# Is there a way to automatically fill in ForeignKey from model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am pretty new to programming but I've run into a bit of a problem and I can't find an answer anywhere; probably because I don't know how to describe the problem very well.

I've made some models: user, customer and contract. Code:

models.py:

```
class CustomerInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_name

class ContractInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerInfo, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    contract_nr = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    contract_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    contract_start = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    contract_end = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contract_nr
```

views.py:

```
def addcontract(request):
    addcontract = AddContractForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddContractForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contr = form.save(commit=False)
            contr.user = request.user
            contr.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Manager:contracts'))
        else:
            form = AddContractForm()
    else:
        form = AddContractForm()
    return render(request,'manager/addcontract.html',{'addcontract':addcontract})
```

forms.py:

```
class AddContractForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = ContractInfo
        exclude = ('user', 'customer',)
        fields = ('contract_nr', 'contract_active', 'contract_start', 'contract_end',)
```

Now I've set it up that people can register and log in. When they register they create a company where they work for (customer). After they're logged in they can add contracts. They only see the contracts they make, trough filtering the contracts for user id by doing: *contr.user = request.user*. However, if they add the contract, the contract is linked to the user and not (yet) the company they belong too. 
Is there a way to automatically fill in the customername/number that they've registered with?
[Image of missing customername](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Vr7.png)

I hope my question is clear and I will edit the question (and title) to make it more clear with your advice.

Comment: Why did you exclude the `customer`?

Comment: That is the field I want to fill in automatically, based on the customer the user registered with. They register with username, email, password and customerinfo (name, chamber of commerce number).
I don't want users to see all available companies in the database.

Comment: but shouldn't `CustomerInfo` than have a `OneToOneField` to user? Right now a `User` can make *multiple* `CustomerInfo` objects (pointing to the same user).

Comment: I thought it would be smart for the admin to be able to add more users to one customer. Do you think it is better to make a OneToOneField and forget about more users? I don't want more than 1 user to be able to 'add' themselves to a company.

Comment: it is not adding more users to one customer, it is adding more customers to one user.

Comment: It should be possible for one person to manage more companies, but again: if it simplifies the code I will definitely make it OneToOne. The times that this situation will occur will be very slim.
Will OneToOne make it easier? What would I have to adjust other than the model?

Comment: but the problem is: imagine a user is logged in, and has multiple `CustomerInfo`s, then what `CustomerInfo` should it take? You can for example add a form field with the `CustomerInfo`s of a `User`, that is perfectly possible, but if there are multiple, there is thus a *semantical* problem (not that much a coding problem, the first part is *what* should be done)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I will re-evaluate the structure of my models. Thank you! :)